# In Python Im trying to read the 5th row of an excel file and use it in a IF statment

Tags: python, excel

```
 def csv_converter(self):
    #gets file
    readfile = pd.read_excel(self.filepath +'//' + self.filename, sheet_name='Details')
    print(readfile.iloc[4])
    if readfile.iloc[4] == 'Company Name: Smiths':
        print('Smiths')
    else:
        print('Harmons')
```

Im trying to read the 5th row of an excel file and find out if says Company Name: Smiths. This is what I got so far but its not printing the names. Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you for your help

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/amp/

Comment: can you post the output from print(readfile.iloc[4])?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the dataframe it is hard to say, but I assume of have multiple columns, so adding the column name to your statment would do it:

```
readfile[<column_name>].iloc[4]
```

`.iloc[4]` access all values of the 5th row, with `readfile[<column_name>]` you define from which column you want to take the value.

Check out the `pandas` documentation for further information:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: The column names/Header doesn't start until the 10th row. Column A1-A9 has basic information about the client. Is there a way to go off the index A5?

Comment: Withouth seeing the data it is hard to say, what the best approach would be. But maybe `if  'Company Name: Smiths' in readfile.iloc[4].tolist():' could do the job